# bucket limit within our S3 account

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure, object-storage

We seemed to have reached the bucket limit within our S3 account, which appears to be 100. The following error was received:

```
AWS Error Message: Account a5b0568e6c2e47cf9a96e81e4610b250@xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx - 

CC_FILTER-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx - CC_FILTER exceeded the container limit.
2017-06-08 11:27:18 ERROR com.xxx.xxx.xxx.samples.TenantManagerTester: Exception running job.
com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: Status Code: 507, AWS Service: Amazon S3, AWS Request ID: f50f5065-d8bf-4252-bf31-f0fbba10e041,
AWS Error Code: ContainerQuotaExceeded, AWS Error Message: Account a5b0568e6c2e47cf9a96e81e4610b250@xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx - CC_FILTER-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx - CC_FILTER
exceeded the container limit, S3 Extended Request ID: null
```

How do we set/configure our container limit? We have requirements which lead to having more than 100 buckets in a container.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=aws+s3+bucket+limit "By default, customers can provision up to 100 buckets per AWS account. However, you can increase your Amazon S3 bucket limit by visiting [AWS Service Limits](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/aws_service_limits.html)."

Answer (score 0):

That is correct, accounts are limited to 100 buckets each.  Instead of creating many buckets, is it possible for your application to use object prefixes instead? Object prefixes use `/` within the object key to organize logical collections of objects within a bucket (docs).

Multiple buckets:

```
PUT https://{bucket-name-1}.{endpoint}/{object-name}
PUT https://{bucket-name-2}.{endpoint}/{object-name}
```

Object prefixes:

```
PUT https://{bucket-name}.{endpoint}/{prefix-1}/{object-name}
PUT https://{bucket-name}.{endpoint}/{prefix-2}/{object-name}
PUT https://{bucket-name}.{endpoint}/{prefix-3a}/{prefix-3b}/{object-name}
PUT https://{bucket-name}.{endpoint}/{prefix-3a}/{prefix-3c}/{object-name}
```

If there's a technical reason that having more buckets is preferable, let me know.  Other users have requested this as well and it's being considered.  What does your use case look like? There's a difference between needing a few thousand buckets and a few hundred thousand buckets. Thanks!

[Documentation link for bucket limitations.](https://ibm-public-cos.github.io/crs-docs/api-reference#create-a-new-bucket)

[Documentation link for listing objects by prefix.](https://ibm-public-cos.github.io/crs-docs/api-reference#list-objects-in-a-given-bucket)

Comment: Thanks for the response and the links above. 
However, we must use buckets because of the nature of the data we are storing.  Near term we are looking at 400 buckets growing to 1000+